# Does there exist a bounded analytic function majorated by a given one?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Let $f$ be an element of the Hardy space $H^2$, i.e. $f$ is an analytic function on the unit disk such that $\sum|a_n|^2<\infty$, where $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$. Assume also that $f\not\equiv 0$.

> Is there a **bounded** function $g\not\equiv 0$ analytic on the unit disk, such that $|g(z)|\le |f(z)|$, for every $z$?

Comment: Yes, because $\log |f(z)|$ is the Poisson integral of a signed measure, and you can define $g$ using its negative part only (or if that is zero, then $|f|$ was bounded below by a positive constant, so everything becomes trivial).

Comment: And I should have first divided out the zeros by using a Blaschke product.